# How to set environment-specific "npm start" commands in .NET 7?

Tags: proxy, single-page-application, package.json, csproj, vs-web-application-project

I'm using .NET Core 7.0, and I created a project based on the *ASP.NET Core with Angular* template, which is a standard template in Visual Studio 2022 (and perhaps in earlier versions too).

The following line was generated automatically in the *.csproj* file when the project was created:

```
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
```

And the `npm start` command is found in the project's *package.json* file, as follows:

```
"start": "ng serve --port 44450",
```

My question is how I can run different npm launch commands based on the environment the program is currently running in. For example, if I change the *package.json* as follows:

```
"startdev": "ng serve --port 44450",
"startprod": "ng serve --port 44451",
```

How do I ensure that the *startdev* command is being used when the project runs in the **Development** environment. Alternatively, how do I ensure that the *startprod* command is being used when the project runs in the **Production** environment?

My best guess is to add the following code to the project's *program.cs* file:

```
webApplication.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (webApplication.Environment.IsProduction())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "startprod");
    }
    else
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "startdev");
    }
});
```

But the [WebApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class doesn't seem to have an *.UseSpa* function, because I get the following error message:

> 'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'UseSpa' and no accessible extension method 'UseSpa' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know how to get it working, and I get the impression (from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/876904/asp-net-6-react-apis) and others) that *.UseSpa* is outdated and has been replaced by the aforementioned *SpaProxyLaunchCommand* (in the *.csproj* file).

**How do I use different *npm* or *ng serve* commands based on whether the program is running in Development or Production?** I'm looking for any solution: if it's possible to do this directly in the *.csproj* or *package.json* file (and not in *program.cs*), then I'd like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted by adding conditions to the *SpaProxyLaunchCommand*, as such:

```
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand Condition="'$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)' == 'Production'">npm run startprod</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand Condition="'$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)' != 'Production'">npm run startdev</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
```